# How do I display a duplicate String multiple times in a Java 8 pipeline?

Tags: java

I have created a pipeline method that is able to take a list of students and the names of the organizations(club) that they joined. I want to generate a list of students that joined multiple clubs, so basically I need to return the duplicate names of students that joined 2 or more clubs. However, it only displays the duplicated names once, instead of something like:

```
 *** Members that joined other organizations within LITERATURECLUB:

 *** Members that joined other organizations within SPORTS:

 *** Members that joined other organizations within MUSIC:

    ** Member: Joey Solydan  

 *** Members that joined other organizations within FILM:

    ** Member: Milles Spielberg  

 *** Members that joined other organizations within ARTS:

    ** Member: Joey Solydan 
    ** Member: Milles Spielberg
```

it would show:

```
 *** Members that joined other organizations within LITERATURECLUB:

 *** Members that joined other organizations within SPORTS:

 *** Members that joined other organizations within MUSIC:

 *** Members that joined other organizations within FILM:

 *** Members that joined other organizations within ARTS:

    ** Member: Joey Solydan 
    ** Member: Milles Spielberg
```

my data.txt file:

```
ARTS:Joey Solydan:Economics
MUSIC:Joey Solydan:Economics 
ARTS:Haley Wolloims:WomenStudies
SPORTS:Godfriey Lemonsquesser:Cookery 
LITERATURECLUB:Say Moniki:Archeology 
FILM:Milles Spielberg:Masscom
ARTS:Milles Spielberg:Masscom
```

I'm not sure why, but once it takes the member's names, it will print to and only for the organization

I have tried creating else if's within the else if block with having the same methods called with but it would show every member instead of members that joined two organizations

Here is my pipeline:

```
 public static void displayDuplicateNames(List<Member> members) {
    Map<String, Integer> duplicateNames = new HashMap<>();//

    members.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Member::getOrg))
            .forEach((org, orgList)-> {
                System.out.printf("%n*** Members that joined other organizations within %s:%n", org);
                   orgList
                           .stream()
                           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Member::getName))
                           .forEach((name, nameList)->{
                               if (duplicateNames.containsKey(name)) {
                                   duplicates.put(name, duplicates.get(name));
                                   System.out.printf("   ** Member: %s %n", name );
                               }
                               else{

                                   duplicateNames.put(name,0);
                               }
                           });

            });
}
```

I need the output as stated from above, all members with two or more clubs be printed in each organization not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time you find a second occurrence of a name, the first one is obviously gone, together with its group.

While it would be possible to build the necessary statistics (count occurrences of organizations, names, faculties) in advance, for example when reading the file itself, if it does not happen that time, you could walk through the list twice:

```
Map<String, Long> duplicateNames =
        members .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Member::getName,
                         Collectors.counting()));
members .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Member::getOrg))
        .forEach((org, orgList) -> {
            System.out.printf("%n*** Members that joined other organizations within %s:%n", org);
            orgList .stream()
                    .map(Member::getName)
                    .filter(name -> duplicateNames.get(name)>1)
                    .forEach(name -> {
                        System.out.printf("   ** Member: %s %n", name );
                    });
        });
```